# Regular Expression: Match number or words, not both

Tags: regex, string, numeric

I need to strip a URL for routing. For that matter the parameters must be checked and redirected accordingly.
The is a need of a regular expression that will check if the parameter is a word(s)(white spaces allowed), or a number (integer - between 1-100).
I know how to get the number.. and the words.. I don't know how to check that it is ONLY one of them, examples bellow.

thanks

```
1            // a match
22           // a match
22a          // not a match
abc          // a match
abc def g    // a match
ab33         // not a match
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(\d+|[A-Za-z\s]+)$
```

You can use this pattern.

Answer (score 1):

```
"222a".match(/^\d+$|^[a-zA-z ]+$/);
null
"222".match(/^\d+$|^[a-zA-z ]+$/);
["222"]
"aaa".match(/^\d+$|^[a-zA-z ]+$/);
["aaa"]
```